# Android Facebook Login get Email

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

I have a simple app with facebook login button and displaying the user info. I am trying to get the user email, used many ways but it gives back a null value. How to get the user email ?

```
loginButton=(LoginButton)findViewById(R.id.loginButton);
loginButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("public_profile", "email"));
callbackManager= CallbackManager.Factory.create();
loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
        loginButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        //how to get user email here
        finish();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancel() {
        Toast.makeText(PopUpFaceBook.this,"تم الغاء تسجيل الدخول",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        finish();
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(FacebookException error) {
        Toast.makeText(PopUpFaceBook.this,"هناك مشكلة فى تسجيل الدخول حاول مجددا",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        finish();
    }
});
```

Comment: Email is nullable. That's mean user is using phone number to log in. Try another account...

Answer (score 1):

Use below code in your `onSuccess()` callback method :

```
LoginResult loginR = loginResult;
// App code
GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(loginResult.getAccessToken(), new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
        Log.v("LoginActivity", response.toString());
        // Application code
        try {
            String email  = object.getString("email");
            String birthday = object.getString("birthday");
            String gender = object.getString("gender");
            String name = object.getString("name");
            // 01/31/1980 format
        } catch (JSONException ex) {
            Log.d("JSonExceptioin", ex.toString());
        }
    }
});
Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
parameters.putString("fields","id,name,email,gender,birthday,picture,timezone");
request.setParameters(parameters);
request.executeAsync();
```

Comment: returns a null value

Comment: @RealDEV This code is correct.try this code with different account. If your account has privacy then facebook will not return email. you can read facebook documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You may use Firebase for this, it will really help you to get all information of facebook profile, such as:
1. Email
2. Name
3. Profile Photo, etc.

Follow steps in below link:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/facebook-login

Thanks